# Not a simple Max

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, max

I have the following data:

```
Id     | Value | OtherStuff
---------------------------
6      | 6     | 1
---------------------------
5      | 4     | 2
---------------------------
5      | 2     | 3
```

The desired result:

```
Id     | Value | OtherStuff
---------------------------
6      | 6     | 1
---------------------------
5      | 4     | 2
```

That is I need the Max Value for each of the Id's.

I'm a bit stumped of how to do this without breaking it into multiple queries, can it be done, and if so how?

Update: I think I oversimplified the issue:

```
var query = from st in StockStakes
            join o in Organisations on j.OrganisationId equals o.OrganisationId into oGroup
            from o in oGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where st.Stock.Status == "A"
            select new
            {
                Id = st.Id,
                Value = st.Value,
                CustomerId = o.OrganisationId
            };
```

The data sample from above still stands... now how do i structure the query to give me the Max Value alongside each Id?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: linq `GoupBy`, then `Max`.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Essentially I need the latest stocktake (Value is a stocktake number) number for each product id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = from x in data
            group x by x.Id into x
            select x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Based on you updated query, similar approach to the first query, but since you have multiple tables you need to group all the tables into an anonymous object and then select only the columns you want

```
var query = from st in StockStakes
            join o in Organisations on j.OrganisationId equals o.OrganisationId into oGroup
            from o in oGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where st.Stock.Status == "A"
            group new { st, o } by st.Id into g
            let largestValue = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                Id = g.Key,
                Value = largestValue.st.Value,
                CustomerId = largestValue.o.OrganisationId
            };
```

Comment: That will only give me the max x.Value... how to configure so that I return Id, Value and OtherStuff ? (But Value is the max value for the Id)

Comment: @PaulZahra - No it will give you the whole record. It is just sorting by the Value

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat... couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about what you mean, but maybe you can try with this query.

```
select Id, max(Value)
from your_table
group by Id;
```

This gives you the max "Value column" value for each "Id column" value.

**-- EDIT --**

LINQ version:

```
var q = from t in dc.YourTable
    group t by t.Id
    into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Id,
        Value = (from t2 in g select t2.Value).Max()
    };
```

Code not tested. I'm on the bus now... :-) Give it a try!

Comment: He's probably needing the linq equivalent to that query.